# Producing git diff for new untracked files

Tags: git

Often I find that I want to share working state in a git tree without making commits/branches using `git diff` and pastebins, email, etc. This works fine when all the changes are modifications to already-tracked files, but not when there are new files involved. I can use `git add -N` to add an empty tracked file to diff against, but this is problematic if I'm going to be committing other things before the changes in question (or if the changes in question are just junk I want to throw away). Is there an easy way to get diffs to add new files included with `git diff` without changing their status in the repository? So far what I have is an ugly script:

```
for i in "$@" ; do diff -u /dev/null "$i" | sed -e 's@^+++ @+++ b/@ ; done
```

Is this the best way?

I'm not entirely opposed to alternate solutions that change the git state as long as it's easy to return to exactly the state before making the change (e.g. with various files modified, some changes staged, etc.)

Comment: This may be too simple, but I would simply `git add <untracked-file>` before `git diff`. Then `git reset <untracked-file>` to un-track it again and you're back where you started.

Comment: @omnikron: The files I want diffs for are not staged yet, so adding it like that would require using `git diff --cached`. If I add it with `git add -N` then use `git reset`, is that safe, or could it destroy the untracked file?

Comment: `git reset` does not destroy anything in your working directory unless you run it with `--hard` argument.

Comment: As you already suggested `git add -N` is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can export untracked, modified or deleted files to an archive like `.tar.gz` and ship them to your colleagues. You can try the following:

- Export modified, moved and deleted files

  `` tar zvcf ~/new-files-cache.tar.gz `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT` ``
- Export Untracked (new), modified and deleted files

  `` tar zvcf ~/new-files-cache.tar.gz ` git status --short | sed 's/^ *[^ ]* \(.*\)/\1/g' ` ``

I found the solutions here: https://manios.org/2014/04/12/export-untracked-modified-moved-and-deleted-files-from-a-git-repository-to-archive